# Change sudo prompt in macos

Tags: macos, command-line, password, sudo, fish

I am trying to change the default sudo prompt that is used in macos to match what I am used to in linux. I want to know that I am expected to put my *sudo* password and not some other password.

I tried the ENV `SUDO_PROMPT` variable prompt first

```
❯ set SUDO_PROMPT '[sudo] %p : '

❯ echo $SUDO_PROMPT
[sudo] %p :

❯ sudo -v
Password:
sudo: a password is required
```

This is not working.

From the [sudo documentation](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.16/sudoers.man/#passprompt_override)

```
passprompt_override
The password prompt specified by passprompt will normally only be used if the 
password prompt provided by systems such as PAM matches the string “Password:”. 
If passprompt_override is set, passprompt will always be used. This flag is off 
by default.
```

Yet when I tried to add this to sudoers file I keep getting an error.
I guess I don't understand how the defaults override in sudo is supposed to work.
There aren't vary good examples of setting boolean flags online that I could find.

```
sudo visudo /etc/sudoers
Password:
#
# Sample /etc/sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.

##
# Override built-in defaults
##
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

# Defaults  passprompt = '[sudo] password for %p: '

#Defautls   passprompt_override
```

Comment: Try `export SUDO_PROMPT='[sudo] %p : '`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Bash or Zsh, variables must be set with

```
export SUDO_PROMPT='[sudo] %p: '
```

If you use Fish, use `set -x` to make the variable available to child processes

```
set -x SUDO_PROMPT '[sudo] %p: '
```

Comment: That is what I tried at the very being of the post. 
I am using the fish shell. So it looks like the problem is with fish.

Comment: @nelaaro Use of non-standard shells is worth mentioning in the question :-)

Comment: @nelaaro Anyway, it's described in file:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/fish/3.5.1/share/doc/fish/cmds/set.html if you installed via Homebrew (and in the answer now as well).

Answer (score 0):

For me the difference in using `fish` `[set][1]` function

```
vim ~/.config/fish/config.fish
set -x SUDO_PROMPT '[sudo] %p : '
```

This is instead of just setting the variable, the `-x` to export is required.
Doing it this way won't work.

```
set SUDO_PROMPT '[sudo] %p : '
```